# How can I force Angular to NOT cache a page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I was told by an old coworker that there's a way to force Angular controller to not cache, and so it'll get the latest data everytime.  I googled and I cannot find the command.. Is there a way to force caching with Angular?  I'm also using Angular UI-Router.

EDIT:

A description of my problem is this.  I'll be on a certain page of my webpage.  Then I click on a button which hits my backend, and if the cookie has expired, it will redirect to the login page.  Once I log in and go back to the page I was originally at, it seems to cache the login page and it'll show the login page instead of the original page that I was at..

The only way to fix it will for me to hard refresh with F5.. that's why I'm trying to find a way to force Angular to not cache.

Comment: Controllers don't cache data; perhaps you should expand your question a bit to explain the real issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Claies updated OP for you

Comment: update doesn't sound like it has anything to do with caching but more to do with your integration of authentication and internal routing. Need to show code

Comment: agreed, this doesn't seem like cached *data*, but a page in your browser history;  without seeing what happens after the login action, it's hard to help.  Also, if by "going back" you mean hitting the back button, there are strategies to remove the login page from the browser history....

Comment: overall, this doesn't sound like caching, it sounds like browser history manipulation.

Comment: the login page goes into a function that checks the database for correct login.. then it'll redirect to the dashboard.  i'll click the link to the page i was originally at and the login will show up instead until i F5..

Comment: that sounds like you are still sending the old cookie, or no cookie at all.   again, without seeing the code that is happening, this isn't really something that we can debug.  There isn't a generic "works in every situation" sort of code fix here.

Comment: because something's wrong in your auth resolve and you need to show the code that manages it and forces the login redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear cache after the event `$viewContentLoaded` is raised :

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
   $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      $templateCache.removeAll();
   });
});
```

[$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) is service where templates are cached when called the first time.

Read more on [$viewContentLoaded](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)

Comment: do you think you can explain how this snippet of code works?